# How to evaluate this integration

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral

How to deal with this integration $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\cdots\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp \left [-\frac{1}{a}\left (\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}+b  \right )^2   \right ]\mathrm{d}x_{1}\cdots\mathrm{d}x_{n},\quad a>0\quad .(1)$$

---

Applying the change of variables formula,let  $y_{1}=x_{1},\dots,y_{n-1}=x_{n-1},y_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i},$then I get $$(1)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\cdots\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp \left [-\frac{1}{a}\left (y_{n}+b  \right )^2   \right ]\mathrm{d}y_{1}\cdots\mathrm{d}y_{n}$$ $$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp \left [-\frac{1}{a}\left (y_{n}+b  \right )^2\right ]\mathrm{d}y_{n}\cdot\coprod_{i=1}^{n-1}\left (  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}1\mathrm{d}y_{i}\right )=\infty.$$
There must be something wrong! But I can't find it.And how to evaluate this integration?

Comment: Nothing wrong. [That integral diverges](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Integrate%5BExp%5B-%28x+%2B+y%29%5E2%5D%2C%7Bx%2C-Infinity%2CInfinity%7D%2C%7By%2C-Infinity%2CInfinity%7D%5D) for all $n > 1$. If you were expecting a convergent integral, perhaps it was $\sum[ (x_i + b)^2]$?

Answer (score 1):

The first integral (the innermost one):

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac1a\left(\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i+b)\right)^2}dx_1=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \sqrt a\, e^{-t^2}dt=\sqrt{a\pi} $$

under the change of variables $\; \frac1{\sqrt a}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i+b)=t\implies dx_1 =\sqrt a\,dt\;$ . And then all the other integrals are infinity, so...it seems like your result is correct.